# How to install TextMate 2 in OS X 10.7 (Lion)?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, textmate-2

Have searched but have not found a TextMate 2 .dmg file available for OS X 10.7 (Lion). Is there one downloadable online?

Also, there are pre-built binaries for TextMate 2 here: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/downloads

However, I downloaded the tar.gz and decompressed it fully, but don't see anything that looks similar to something I could put into the Applications directory. *Update: The zip/tar.gz of the repo was removed, so you can intuitively download the .tbz and decompress it to get the app now.*

Comment: I just downloaded it and the first one to decompress is *.tbz* then it gives me a *.tar*.  After decompressing that one, it gave me *TextMate.app*, which is the Application.  Did you go that deep?  (Using 7zip)

Comment: Yeah, when I click on "Download as tar.gz" and then double-click on `textmate-textmate-921efb9.tar.gz` to have OS X decompress it, it generates a `textmate-textmate-921efb9` directory that contains a number of directories, but didn't look like it was the app directory. The .tbz didn't have that problem, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the latest TextMate 2.0 from the TextMate homepage, under

http://macromates.com/download

It used to be available from [GitHub](https://github.com/textmate/textmate), but pre-builds are no longer necessary since TextMate 2 now includes an auto-update mechanism.

Comment: Ah! I see now. Neither the zip from "Download as .zip" nor the tar.gz "Download as tar.gz" contain the .app, but the .tbz does. Thanks!

Comment: True, the above would give you the snapshot of the complete repository, where you'd have to build it yourself according to the README.